# LINQ to XML Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've got a simple POCO class to hold data extracted from an XML file defined as follows:

```
public class Demographics
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I've got a fairly straight-forward XML file (or rather element in this case) to extract data from, defined as follows:

```
<patient determinerCode="INSTANCE">
    <name use="L">
        <given>John</given>
        <given qualifier="IN">Q.</given>
        <family>Public</family>
    </name>
    <administrativeGenderCode code="F" displayName="Female"/>   
</patient>
```

The challenge I'm having is getting the middle initial and/or first name into the correct properties in my class.  As you can see, there are two ***given*** nodes inside the ***name*** node and the middle initial is designated by an "IN" attribute.  Is there a simply LINQ syntax that I'm missing here, or do I need to query for all the given nodes and enumerate through them to properly place each node?

My code as it currently stands, looks like this:

```
private string GetInterfaceXmlData(XElement source)
{
        //Source in this context represents the "patient" element as you see in the example.
        //The NMSPC constant represents the namespace for this XML document which is not specifically displayed
        //in the XML example.
        Demographics currentDemo = new Demographics()
        {
            //I realize that this particular reference to FirstName is not optimal, as it may not actually
            //be the first "given" node under the name node, it's simply a place holder for now.
            FirstName = source.Element(NMSPC + "name").Element(NMSPC + "given").Value,
            LastName = source.Element(NMSPC + "name").Element(NMSPC + "family").Value,
            Gender=source.Element(NMSPC+"administrativeGenderCode").Attribute("code").Value,
        };
        XElement result = new XElement("XML");
        result.Add(new XElement("Demographics"));
        return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
// For the first name
source.Element(NMSPC + "name")
      .Elements(NMSPC + "given")
      .Where(element => element.Attribute("IN") == null)
      .First()

// For the initial
source.Element(NMSPC + "name")
      .Elements(NMSPC + "given")
      .Where(element => element.Attribute("IN") != null)
      .First()
```

EDIT: Query syntax is a bit awkward here. For the first version, it would be:

```
(from element in .Element(NMSPC + "name").Elements(NMSPC + "given")
where element.Attribute("IN") == null
select element).First()
```

I'd personally stick to dot notation for this.

Comment: OK, as I see this it seems a little obvious.  I was a bit hung up on using query syntax which may have been my downfall.  If you have time, would you mind dropping in a responce in that syntax?  I'd like to see where I was going wrong there as well.  As always, thanks very much Jon.

Comment: Thanks again.  I see your point about query syntax being awkward.